# Collecting Data from Repository and ViewModel when using Coroutines and Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, android-room, coroutine

**Hello everyone,**
I am currently working on a caching app where I encounter the following situation: The DAO function returns a Flow<List> representing a stream of data from the local database. In the repository, I collect the data from the DAO function, and in the ViewModel, I collect the data from the repository function.

I would like to discuss the best practices for collecting data from both the repository and the ViewModel. Is it considered a good practice to collect the data in both places? Are there any potential drawbacks or issues with this approach?

To provide more information, the local database serves as the *source of truth* for the app, and the primary data handling occurs there. Since the DAO function returns a Flow<List> and the repository function returns a Flow<List>, it seems necessary to collect the data from the DAO function within the repository to observe updates from the database.

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions, and experiences regarding the best practices for collecting data from both the repository and the ViewModel while considering the usage of coroutines and Flow.

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface MovieDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun saveMovies(moviesEntity: MoviesEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movies")
    fun getMovies(): Flow<List<MoviesEntity>>?

    @Query("DELETE FROM movies")
    suspend fun clearMoviesListing()

}
```

interface MovieRepository:

```
interface MovieRepository {

    fun getMoviesResult(
        category: String,
        fetchFromRemote: Boolean,
    ): Flow<Resource<List<Movies>>>
}
```

MovieRepositoryImpl:

```
@RequiresExtension(extension = Build.VERSION_CODES.S, version = 7)
class MovieRepositoryImpl(
    private val movieApi: MovieApi,
    private val movieDao: MovieDao
) : MovieRepository {


    override fun getMoviesResult(
        category: String,
        fetchFromRemote: Boolean
    ): Flow<Resource<List<Movies>>> {

        return flow {

            while (true) {
                emit(Resource.Loading(true))

                movieDao.getMovies()?.collect { localListing ->

                    if (localListing.isNotEmpty() && !fetchFromRemote) {
                        emit(Resource.Loading(false))

                        emit(
                            Resource.Success(data = localListing.map {
                                it.toMovies()
                            })
                        )
                    } else {

                        val remoteListing = try {
                            movieApi.getMovies(category = category)
                        } catch (e: IOException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            emit(Resource.Error("Couldn't Reach Server, Check Your Internet Connection, Try Refresh"))
                            null
                        } catch (e: HttpException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            emit(Resource.Error("Couldn't Reach Server, Check Your Internet Connection."))
                            null
                        }

                        if (remoteListing !== null) {

                            emit(Resource.Loading(false))

                            remoteListing.let { movie ->

                                movieDao.clearMoviesListing()

                                movieDao.saveMovies(movie.toMoviesEntity())

                                movieDao.getMovies()!!.collect() { movieEntity ->

                                    emit(
                                        Resource.Success(data = movieEntity.map {
                                            it.toMovies()
                                        })
                                    )
                                }


                            }
                        }
                        emit(Resource.Error(message = ""))

                        emit(Resource.Loading(false))
                    }


                }
            }


        }

    }
}
```

MovieScreenViewModel:

```
    private fun getMovieResult(category: String, fetchFromRemote: Boolean) {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            movieRepository.getMoviesResult(category, fetchFromRemote)

                .collect { results ->

                    when (results) {

                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            results.data?.let { result ->
                                state = state.copy(movies = result)
                            }
                        }

                        is Resource.Error ->
                            state = state.copy(
                                error = results.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred"
                            )

                        is Resource.Loading -> state = state.copy(isLoading = results.isLoading)

                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

**Thank you for your valuable input!**

I am unsure if it is appropriate to collect the data again in the ViewModel or if there is a more efficient approach. I want to ensure that I am following best practices and making optimal use of coroutines and Flow in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I am also pretty new to android developing but according to Android's general guidelines you should use in your view model something like :

```
lateinit var movieListLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<Movies>>

private fun getMovieResult(category: String, fetchFromRemote: Boolean) {
     movieListLiveData = movieRepository.getMoviesResult(category, fetchFromRemote).asLiveData()
}
```

And work with that live data to update your UI

> The asLiveData operator converts a Flow into a LiveData with a configurable timeout.
> Just like the liveData builder, the timeout will help the Flow survive restart. If another screen observes before the timeout, the Flow won't be cancelled.